# Changing the size of a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I want to make a dynamic photo gallery.

I am loading the pictures into a `UIImageView` and it works as it should.

The problem is that I don't know how to scale the pictures down.

```
self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){
        .origin=CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width*x, 0.00+z), 
        .size=self.scrollView.bounds.size
    };
```

I tried stuff like `.width` but it does not work.

Comment: I don't see how is this related to Xcode...

Comment: does the ios not run on xocde ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally figure it out

the .origin and . size are just a shorter way to write the size down

a better way is

```
   self.imageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=self.view.bounds.size.width*x, 0.00,300,300

    };
```